# Magento 1.9.3.8 Easy way to check if all the products assigned to any category (category products) are enabled?

Tags: product, php, magento1.9.3

Is there an easy check for this that works out of the box?: if all the products assigned to any category (category products; in the configuration of any category in the backend) are enabled? -if loop or something-.

All products are simple products.

Comment: Get product collection script that will  be best way

Comment: Hi Rahul; do you have any link with background information for me with regard to get the production collection ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087798/magento-get-product-collection-of-all-products you will get the collection